# Fix this code with f-string for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

while I read [this](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex24.html)

that has this code

```
We can also do that this way:
We'd have 500000 beans, 500 jars, and 5 crates.
```

when I revised to pep 498

```
print ("We can also do that this way:")
print (f"We'd have {secret_formula(start_point)} beans, {secret_formula(start_point)} jars, and {secret_formula(start_point)} crates.")
```

it print this

```
We can also do that this way:
We'd have (500000, 500, 5) beans, (500000, 500, 5) jars, and (500000, 500, 5) crates.
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are following `LPTHW` tutorial, which I `strongly` suggest you pick up a different tutorial, as the current one you have has some very *interesting* opinions and [some other issues](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

Back to your question: you need to unpack the `secret_formula()` call to be:

```
b, j, c = secret_formula(start_point)

print (f"We'd have {b} beans, {j} jars, and {c} crates.")
```

`f-strings` are basically just placing the variable in the string to call it and since the `secret_formula()` returns a tuple, when you fstring just calling the function, it will return and print the tuple.

Comment: Do you have any books on python 3 for me?

Comment: how to print this code with f-string?

```
print('{0:_^11}'.format('hello'))
```

Comment: @kunjun the same way you would with `.format()` like this: `print(f'{x:_^11}')`

Answer (score 0):

this code I want to fix into f-string

`print "We can also do that this way:"
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)`